# Forget grid row or column configuration in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, row, reset

I wonder if is possible remove row and column configure in tkinter. For example:

I configure the row and column:

```py
myframe = CTkFrame(master)

myframe.grid_rowconfigure(0)
myframe.grid_columnconfigure(0)
```

Now let's say that I configure a column number:

```py
myframe.grid_columnconfigure(10)
```

If I don't need more the column 9 and 10, how I configure again or reset the configurations on the frame?

**EDITED**

Sorry, my question is wrong, like @Bryan Oakley say, grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure don't change nothing. It question is closed.

Another doubt that it answer give me is so, how can I do the grid occupy his weight without a content? And how can I forget it. I know that I can create a blank widget on the extremities of the grid, and forget the widget when I want reset the occupation. But if have a way to do it without a blank widget, I can know.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking, since `myframe.grid_columnconfigure(10)` doesn't actually configure anything -- there's nothing to reset.

Comment: Again, `columnconfigure(8)` doesn’t actually change anything so there is nothing to reset.

Comment: `grid` isn't a widget, it's instructions for adding widgets. If you don't add something to a row or column, it doesn't exist. For an empty row or column to exist, it needs to have something in it or be given an explicit minimum size using some combination of the `minsize`, `weight`, and `uniform` options.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to do it. Though, the column won't "show", but space will be allocated for those columns. `grid` isn't a visible widget, it's a method for arranging widgets. There won't be any grid lines, for example.

Comment: Ok, I understand, you can make a answer with these informations, pleasy? Thank you